# Android transparent background shows as black in Photos

Tags: android

I'm using the below code to remove the background from an image, which does work fine, but when i save the image to device, as you can see the background becomes black?

```
object BackgroundRemover {

private val segment: Segmenter
private var buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(0)
private var width = 0
private var height = 0


init {
    val segmentOptions = SelfieSegmenterOptions.Builder()
        .setDetectorMode(SelfieSegmenterOptions.SINGLE_IMAGE_MODE)
        .build()
    segment = Segmentation.getClient(segmentOptions)
}


/**
 * Process the image to get buffer and image height and width
 * @param bitmap Bitmap which you want to remove background.
 * @param trimEmptyPart After removing the background if its true it will remove the empty part of bitmap. by default its false.
 * @param listener listener for success and failure callback.
 **/
fun bitmapForProcessing(
    bitmap: Bitmap,
    trimEmptyPart: Boolean = false,
    listener: OnBackgroundChangeListener
) {
    //Generate a copy of bitmap just in case the if the bitmap is immutable.
    val copyBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)
    val input = InputImage.fromBitmap(copyBitmap, 0)
    segment.process(input)
        .addOnSuccessListener { segmentationMask ->
            buffer = segmentationMask.buffer
            width = segmentationMask.width
            height = segmentationMask.height

            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                val time = measureTimeMillis {
                    val resultBitmap = if (trimEmptyPart) {
                        val bgRemovedBitmap = removeBackgroundFromImage(copyBitmap)
                        trim(bgRemovedBitmap)
                    } else {
                        removeBackgroundFromImage(copyBitmap)
                    }
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        listener.onSuccess(resultBitmap)
                    }
                }
                Log.e("TAG", "bitmapForProcessingTime: $time")
            }

        }
        .addOnFailureListener { e ->
            println("Image processing failed: $e")
            listener.onFailed(e)

        }
}


/**
 * Change the background pixels color to transparent.
 * */
private suspend fun removeBackgroundFromImage(
    image: Bitmap
): Bitmap {
    val bitmap = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async {
        for (y in 0 until height) {
            for (x in 0 until width) {
                val bgConfidence = ((1.0 - buffer.float) * 255).toInt()
                if (bgConfidence >= 100) {
                    image.setPixel(x, y, Color.TRANSPARENT)
                }
            }
        }
        buffer.rewind()
        return@async image
    }
    return bitmap.await()
}


/**
 * trim the empty part of a bitmap.
 **/
private suspend fun trim(
    bitmap: Bitmap
): Bitmap {
    val result = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).async {
        var firstX = 0
        var firstY = 0
        var lastX = bitmap.width
        var lastY = bitmap.height
        val pixels = IntArray(bitmap.width * bitmap.height)
        bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, bitmap.width, 0, 0, bitmap.width, bitmap.height)
        loop@ for (x in 0 until bitmap.width) {
            for (y in 0 until bitmap.height) {
                if (pixels[x + y * bitmap.width] != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                    firstX = x
                    break@loop
                }
            }
        }
        loop@ for (y in 0 until bitmap.height) {
            for (x in firstX until bitmap.width) {
                if (pixels[x + y * bitmap.width] != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                    firstY = y
                    break@loop
                }
            }
        }
        loop@ for (x in bitmap.width - 1 downTo firstX) {
            for (y in bitmap.height - 1 downTo firstY) {
                if (pixels[x + y * bitmap.width] != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                    lastX = x
                    break@loop
                }
            }
        }
        loop@ for (y in bitmap.height - 1 downTo firstY) {
            for (x in bitmap.width - 1 downTo firstX) {
                if (pixels[x + y * bitmap.width] != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                    lastY = y
                    break@loop
                }
            }
        }
        return@async Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, firstX, firstY, lastX - firstX, lastY - firstY)
    }
    return result.await()
}
```

}[background removed image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZaZL.png) [image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see black in the background of your image is because your image is not using the alpha channel.

```
val c : Canvas = Canvas(bm); // bitmap
c.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);
```

Bitmap created in mode **ARGB_8888** supports transparency

Update this method like this.

```
private suspend fun removeBackgroundFromImage(
    image: Bitmap
): Bitmap {
    val bitmap = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async {
        for (y in 0 until height) {
            for (x in 0 until width) {
                val bgConfidence = ((1.0 - buffer.float) * 255).toInt()
                if (bgConfidence >= 100) {
                    image.setHasAlpha(true)
                    image.setPixel(x, y, Color.TRANSPARENT)
                }
            }
        }
        buffer.rewind()
        return@async image
    }
    return bitmap.await()
}
```

I just added `image.setHasAlpha(true)`.

**setHasAlpha**

> Tell the bitmap if all of the pixels are known to be opaque (false) or
> if some of the pixels may contain non-opaque alpha values (true).
> Note, for some configs (e.g. RGB_565) this call is ignored, since it
> does not support per-pixel alpha values. This is meant as a drawing
> hint, as in some cases a bitmap that is known to be opaque can take a
> faster drawing case than one that may have non-opaque per-pixel alpha
> values.

Comment: Could you clarify where this is supposed to go? From my understanding the bitmap is created with mode ARGB_888 here     val copyBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)